# jQuery Lazyload with highest z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to lazy load a fullscreen website with no scrolling, basically all the pages are stacked ontop of each other with z-index and changes pages just switches the z-index on elements. But lazy load does not seem to see this and the page still tries to load everything. Some elements have `display:none` and other have `visibility: hidden.`

I basically just need a script that makes sure that anything within in the element with the highest z-index loads, but everything else is on hold until it becomes the element with the highest z-index.

Here is a fiddle but with no js yet as a base if anyone knows how i could do this?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamsynk/dbngco7q/

Answer (score 2):

If you got the time you can easily write a jQuery plugin to do so, you can use [`:in-viewport`](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) and `:visible` to filter the images, you can also pre-load images before they become visible.

Use `data-` attributes to set the image url, and use an empty image initially for your photos, then change the desired attribute (`src` or `background`) to the corresponding `data-` attribute and it should load.